# how to check the string has been convert to vector into the data in R?

Tags: r

i wanna change my *string input* to vector that can checked to my data.
this my string input,

```
input<-("i am a student")
```

i have been change it to vector with code bellow

```
a<-unlist(strsplit(input, "[ ]"))
```

the result

```
[1] "i" "am" "a" "student"
```

i want check one word by word to my data.
ex: "i" checked to my data,  "am" checked to my data, etc.

but it didn't checked to my data.
my code to check to my data, in this bellow

```
if (a %in% kamus)   
    return(a)    
  else return("nothing")
```

*kamus* is the name of my data that content million of words.

example of function that i have been made

```
> cek_kamus<- function(input){
+       if (input %in% kamus)
+         kata3<-return(input)
+       else return("nothing")
+ 
+ }
```

to check my input in kamus

```
> cek_kamus("and")
```

and the result

```
[1] "and"
```

but if nothing in kamus will showed bellow or check to my next iteration.

```
> cek_kamus("dpat")  
[1] "nothing"
```

so, i want my input is more than 1 word without make manual vector in R like

```
> input<-c("i", "am", "a", "student") 
> sapply(input,cek_kamus)
        i        am         a   student 
      "i"      "am"       "a" "nothing"
```

i want your helping to give me the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `ifelse`

```
ifelse(a %in% kamus, a, "nothing")
```

---

BTW, the `a %in% kamus` returns a logical vector.  It is only due to the OP's post, we showed the `ifelse` to change the values

#### Update

Based on the update in the function,

```
cek_kamus<- function(input){
   input <- unlist(strsplit(input, "\\s+"))
   ifelse(input %in% kamus, input, "nothing")            
   }

kamus <- c('ad', 'am', 'student')

cek_kamus('i am a student')
#[1] "nothing" "am"      "nothing" "student"
```

Comment: In if (a %in% kamus) return(a) : has the warning massege that is,  
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. @akrun

Comment: @sarah You haven't provided a reproducible example, so, it is not clear

Comment: ok @akrun i will edit my post. plis correct again :) thank you

Comment: @sarah In that case, u can use `sapply(input, cek_kamus)` as you showed in the post.  Also, the solution can be done with `ifelse` if you check my first solution

Comment: @sarah With the `ck_kamus("i am a student")` what is your expected output?

Comment: yes. it worth it. but i mean i give my input without manual vector like 
`input<-c('i', 'am', 'a', 'student')`
`sapply(input, cek_kamus)`
but i want my input like `ck_kamus("i am a student")`
@akrun

Comment: i expect  `"i"  "am"  "a" "nothing"` @akrun

Answer (score 0):

Just using `b <- (a %in% kamus)` will give you a vector `b` the same length as `a`, with `TRUE` or `FALSE` values if the relevant member of `a` is in `kamus`.

You could then do `df <- data.frame(word=a,inKamus=b,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` to create a table with the words and whether they are in `kamus`.

Or `a[b]` will be just those members of `a` in `kamus`, and `a[!b]` will be those not in it, etc.

Or, use a function like this...

```
cek_kamus<- function(input){
  b <- (input %in% kamus)
  input <- ifelse(b,input,"nothing")
  return(input)
  }
```

This should work as `cek_kamus(input)` without having to use `sapply`.

Comment: but it just return TRUE and FALSE value. i want the string too. @Andrew Gustar

Comment: I have added some ways of doing this above.

Comment: i have adited my post. can you help me again? @Andrew Gustar